# What's the best device to create Anchor and what's the maximum number of near anchor can be handle?

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I try to map a large area with Azure Spatial Anchor. I noticed that the quality of the anchor between Android and iOS is not really the same but i don't have hololens to test. So what's the best device to have the best anchor quality (position and relationship) ?

I also need to create multiple anchor in the same session to allow my user to localize everywhere so i'm wondering how many anchor the device can handle for really large area (1000+) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both iOS and Android should yield the same quality of anchors based on your device resources.

The amount of anchors per session its driven by resources available in your device. If you are seeing issues creating large number of anchors in one session you can use a multi session approach. You should be able to create multiple anchors that are linked together across different session.

**[Connect anchors across sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/concepts/anchor-relationships-way-finding#connect-anchors-in-multiple-sessions)**